# Proving property of union of events using axioms of probability

Tags: probability, probability-theory

> Prove using the axioms of probability that if $A_{n-1} \subset A_n$ and $A = \bigcup\limits_{i=1}^{\infty} A_{i}$
>   then $P (A) = \lim_{n\to\infty} P(A_n)$

I thought that maybe taking a fixed $n$ i could prove that $P(A) = P(A_n)$ (using that the union of all $A_i$ is $A_n$) but i don't know where to go from here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Letting $B_n = A_n - A_{n-1}$, we have $\bigcup_1^n B_i = \bigcup_1^n A_i = A_n$, so by countable additivity,
\begin{align*}
P(A) = P(\cup_1^{\infty} A_i) = P(\cup_1^{\infty}B_i) = \lim_{n\to\infty}\sum_{i=1}^{n}P(B_i) = \lim_{n\to\infty} P(\cup_1^n B_i) = \lim_{n\to\infty}P(A_n),
\end{align*}
where the third equality follows by the disjointness of the $B_n$'s.

Comment: I don't understand why would you split the probabilities of the $B_i$ into the sum to join them again then. I mean, the only thing that i see is that you put the limit of n tending to infinity which as i understand is the definition itself of the sum of infinit things. Couldn't you do it in the previous step with the union?

Comment: No. Without applying the countable additivity property, you are directly using the continuity from below property which you set out to prove.

Answer (score 2):

Hint: Consider the sequence $(B_n)_{n \geq 1}$ defined by $B_n=A_n-A_{n-1}$

What can you say about this sequence? Can you apply any of the axioms to it?